# Doobie update and insert case class syntax

Tags: scala, doobie

Doobie can `select *` with a case class for convenient and correct parameter passing, but I don't see how to work in a similar way with `update` and `insert`.

For example, given a case class like this:

```scala
case class Course(
  sku: String,
  title: String,
  id: Id,
  price: Int,
  instructorid: Id,
  groupid: Id,
  shortdescription: String = "",
  transcript: String = "",
  project_home: String = "",
  repository: String = "",
  category: String = "",
  image: String = "",
  privacy: String = "",
  language: String = "",
  keywords: String = "",
  goals: String = "",
  instructionallevel: String = "",
  audience: String = "",
  studenttasks: String =  "",
  sections: String = "",
  active: Boolean = true,
  video: String = "",
  paypal_button_id: String = "",
  prerequisite_ids: String = ""
)
```

I can nicely `select` records. This nice syntax is possible because Doobie iterates through the `Course` case class properties and assigns values to them by matching their names to the `courses` database record fields:

```scala
    def find(id: Id): Option[Course] =
      sql"select * from courses where id = $id"
        .query[Course]
        .option
        .transact(SQLSupport.xa)
        .unsafeRunSync
```

However `insert` requires all of the case class properties to be manually listed, and matched up with values, which is horrible and error-prone:

```scala
    /** @return saved Course with new Id */
    def save(course: Course): Course = {
      val insert: doobie.ConnectionIO[Course] = sql"""insert into courses (
          sku,
          title,
          price,
          instructorid,
          groupid,
          shortdescription,
          transcript,
          project_home,
          repository,
          category,
          image,
          privacy,
          language,
          keywords,
          goals,
          instructionallevel,
          audience,
          studenttasks,
          sections,
          active,
          video,
          paypal_button_id,
          prerequisite_ids
        ) values (
          ${ course.sku },
          ${ course.title },
          ${ course.price },
          ${ course.instructorid },
          ${ course.groupid },
          ${ course.shortdescription },
          ${ course.transcript },
          ${ course.project_home },
          ${ course.repository },
          ${ course.category },
          ${ course.image },
          ${ course.privacy },
          ${ course.language },
          ${ course.keywords },
          ${ course.goals },
          ${ course.instructionallevel },
          ${ course.audience },
          ${ course.studenttasks },
          ${ course.sections },
          ${ course.active },
          ${ course.video },
          ${ course.paypal_button_id },
          ${ course.prerequisite_ids }
        )"""
        .update
        .withUniqueGeneratedKeys("id")
      val newCourse: Course = insert.transact(SQLSupport.xa).unsafeRunSync
      newCourse
    }
```

Also `update` is similarly horrible:

```scala
    /** @return updated Course, which should be identical to the given course */
    def update(course: Course): Course = {
      val update: doobie.ConnectionIO[Course] = sql"""update courses set
          sku = ${ course.sku },
          title = ${ course.title },
          id = ${ course.id },
          price = ${ course.price },
          instructorid = ${ course.instructorid },
          groupid = ${ course.groupid },
          shortdescription = ${ course.shortdescription },
          transcript = ${ course.transcript },
          project_home = ${ course.project_home },
          repository = ${ course.repository },
          category = ${ course.category },
          image = ${ course.image },
          privacy = ${ course.privacy },
          language = ${ course.language },
          keywords = ${ course.keywords },
          goals = ${ course.goals },
          instructionallevel = ${ course.instructionallevel },
          audience = ${ course.audience },
          studenttasks = ${ course.studenttasks },
          sections = ${ course.sections },
          active = ${ course.active },
          video = ${ course.video },
          paypal_button_id = ${ course.paypal_button_id },
          prerequisite_ids = ${ course.prerequisite_ids }
        where id = ${ course.id }"""
        .update
        .withUniqueGeneratedKeys("id")
      val modifiedCourse: Course = update.transact(SQLSupport.xa).unsafeRunSync
      modifiedCourse
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It seems there is a `Write` typeclass designed for this purpose: https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html#column-vector-mappings
but I can't find how to use it...

Comment: These issues seem related: https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/1328 and https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/902

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Doobie` documentation is quite great, but sometimes you might find yourself in some scenarios that are not directly explained in their docs.

In order to insert directly a `case class` object (not their attributes), you must define a `Write[A]` which will tells `Doobie` how the data must be inserted. This is used when the mapping of the attributes, in the case class, are slightly different from the ones in the database table.

Imagine the following case class:

```
case class Course (id: UUID, name: String, year: Int)
```

In this case, we need to define a `Write[Course]` for doobie, which would be:

```
// Scala 3:
given Write[Course] = Write[(UUID, String, Int)].contramap(c => (c.id, c.name, c.year))

// Scala 2:
implicit val writer : Write[Course] = Write[(UUID, String, Int)].contramap(c => (c.id, c.name, c.year))
```

So now, you can run your `Update` and `Doobie` will know how to map your columns:

```
def insertCourse(course: Course): Update0 =
    sql"""INSERT INTO courses (id, name, year) VALUES ($course)""".update
```

Also, you might need these imports:

```
import doobie.implicits.*
import doobie.implicits.javasql.*
import doobie.postgres.implicits.*
import doobie.*
```

If your `case class` attributes and their types exactly matches with those specified in the table of the database, you don't need to manually specify the `Writer[Course]` because Doobie will automatically derivate it for you [[1](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html)] and this should work for you:

```
case class Course (id: UUID, name: String, year: Int)

def insertCourse(course: Course): Update0 =
  sql"""INSERT INTO courses (id, name, year) VALUES ($course)""".update
```

> Credits to my partner Y.C. that helped me to resolve this issue!

Comment: Thanks for helping out. This code shows the `writer`'s properties listed out manually. This gets tedious fast. Is there not a way that the public properties of a case class be persisted by default? ... even better, automagic property enumeration for Reader and Writer?

Comment: @MikeSlinn I just tried again the same code, but without specifying the `Writer[Course]` and it seems that Doobie automatics derivation works well to generate it for us. I've updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 2):

A little note: in case anyone also encountered

```
doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment[_]; incompatible interpolation method sql
```

while following David Corral example:

instead of

```
def insertCourse(course: Course): Update0 =
sql"""INSERT INTO courses (id, name, year) VALUES ($course)""".update
```

try wrapping course variable in Fragments

```
def insertCourse(course: Course): Update0 =
sql"""INSERT INTO courses (id, name, year) VALUES (${Fragments.values(course)})""".update
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres, you could take a look at another library of Rob Norris - [skunk](https://github.com/tpolecat/skunk/).

It allows you to write custom codecs:

```
  case class City(id: Int, name: String, code: String, district: String, pop: Int)

  val city: Codec[City] =
    (int4 ~ varchar ~ bpchar(3) ~ varchar ~ int4).gimap[City]

  val insertCity: Command[City] =
    sql"""
         INSERT INTO city
         VALUES ($city)
       """.command
```

[Check examples](https://github.com/tpolecat/skunk/blob/057c59c284f670a4b9616d0912add0c4714a8caa/modules/tests/src/test/scala/CommandTest.scala).

Answer (score 0):

Doobie has Quill integration from [getquill.io](https://getquill.io) which allows you to model sql DML's using case classes
https://github.com/polyvariant/doobie-quill

Comment: Doobie / Quill docs are very, very thin. Not enough info to be usable in a reasonable time period.

Comment: I meant that the docs on the integration do not say much. In particular, no examples show how the 2 products work together to add value.

Comment: Doobie is no longer officially supporting Quill and the library and docs have been removed from Doobie's site.

Comment: It is supported externally https://github.com/polyvariant/doobie-quill